# Can I create a Sas key for a directory in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

In azure blob storage, I can create a Sas key with read permissions for a specific file, or a container, but can't do this for a directory.

Is there a way in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 to create a Sas key that will allow access to a directory and all the files in it? If there is a way, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, we cannot create a `SAS` key for a directory in `Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2`, but you can set file and directory level permissions by using [access control lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control#access-control-lists-on-files-and-directories).

`.net` as an example, this example gets and sets the ACL of a directory named `my-directory`. The string `user::rwx,group::r-x,other::rw-` gives the owning user read, write, and execute permissions, gives the owning group only read and execute permissions, and gives all others read and write permission.

```
public async Task ManageDirectoryACLs(DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient)
{
    DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient =
        fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient("my-directory");

    PathAccessControl directoryAccessControl =
        await directoryClient.GetAccessControlAsync();

    foreach (var item in directoryAccessControl.AccessControlList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }


    IList<PathAccessControlItem> accessControlList
        = PathAccessControlExtensions.ParseAccessControlList
        ("user::rwx,group::r-x,other::rw-");

    directoryClient.SetAccessControlList(accessControlList);

}
```

For specific practices and instructions, you can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-dotnet#manage-a-directory-acl).

Answer (score 0):

Now you can create Directory level SAS.